# При помощи Сканера удалить элементы Set

Tags: java, коллекции

Написать class `Student`, в мейне создать Сет и заполнить его Студентами.
Используя `Scanner`, `Iterator` создать возможность удаления элементов Сета введеным именем в консоле, после чего вывести на экран без удаленного элемента

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Student> students = new HashSet<>();
        students.add(new Student("Anton", 33, "Male", 88.3));
        students.add(new Student("Ira", 21, "Female", 38.3));
        students.add(new Student("Petro", 27, "Male", 46.3));

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter who:  ");
        String fromUser = scan.next();

        Iterator<Student> iterator = students.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Student next = iterator.next();
            if (next.getName() == fromUser) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }

        for (Student student : students) {
            System.out.println(student);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените

```
if (next.getName() == fromUser) {
```

на

```
if (next.getName().equals(fromUser)) {
```

Проблема в том, что для объектов оператор `==` проверяет значения ссылок, что у разных объектов будет отличаться

---

```
class Student {
    private String name;

    Student(String name, int age, String sex, double weight) {
        this.name = name;
        // ...
    }

    String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Student <'%s'>", name);
    }
}

// ...

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Student> students = new HashSet<>();
    students.add(new Student("Anton", 33, "Male", 88.3));
    students.add(new Student("Ira", 21, "Female", 38.3));
    students.add(new Student("Petro", 27, "Male", 46.3));

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter who: ");
    String fromUser = scan.next();

    Iterator<Student> iterator = students.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Student next = iterator.next();
        if (next.getName().equals(fromUser)) {
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }

    for (Student student : students) {
        System.out.println(student);
    }
}
```

Консоль:

```
Enter who: Ira
Student <'Anton'>
Student <'Petro'>
```

---

**PS.**

Начиная с java 8, цикл с итератором можно заменить на эту конструкцию:

```
students.removeIf(next -> next.getName().equals(fromUser));
```